# Selenium: Extract attribute values from HTML Table

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, html-parsing

[link that contain the HTML table](http://water.nt.gov.au/cgi/webhyd.pl?dwhswdf_org=G0010005&cat=dwhsw&lvl=1&)

Here is the XML text

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <body onkeyup="return key_up(event,'dwhswdf_org')" onload="onLoad()" style="padding: 0px;">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <head>
    <body>
    <div id="dark"></div>
    <div id="light"></div>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="cattext"></div>
    <div id="titletext"></div>
    <div id="tabstext"></div>
    <br>
    <table width="1%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td width="1%" valign="top">
    <b>Details</b>
    <table width="1%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>Site no.</td>
    <td>G0010005</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Site commence</td>
    <td>09/08/1965</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Zero gauge</td>
    <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Datum</td>
    <td>GD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <tr>
    <tr>
    <tr>
    <tr>
    <tr>
    <tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" align="left">
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <style type="text/css">
    </body>
    <script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My question is How can I extract HTML table elements  G0010005, 09/08/1965, 0 having attribute name 'Site no.', 'Site commence', 'Zero gauge' respectively using selenium package in python. I tried to extract using few arguments but none of them worked for me. Below is the code i have written so far...

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver  = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> driver.get("https://water.nt.gov.au/cgi/webhyd.pl?dwhswdf_org=G0010005&cat=dwhsw&lvl=1&")
>>> tbl = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//html/body/body/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")
>>> tb1.get_attribute()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    get_attribute(tb1)
NameError: name 'get_attribute' is not defined

>>> tbl = driver.find_element_by_name("Site no.")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    tbl = driver.find_element_by_name("Site no.")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 365, in find_element_by_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 752, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [name="Site no."]

>>> tbl = driver.find_element_by_text('Site no.')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    tbl = driver.find_element_by_text('Site no.')
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_text'
```

any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://water.nt.gov.au/cgi/webhyd.pl?dwhswdf_org=G0010005&cat=dwhsw&lvl=1&')
siteNoEle = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//td[text()='Site no.']/following-sibling::td[1]")
siteNo = siteNoEle.text
print siteNo

siteCommenceEle = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//td[text()='Site commence']/following-sibling::td[1]")
siteCommence = siteCommenceEle.text
print siteCommence


zeroEle = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//td[text()='Zero gauge']/following-sibling::td[1]")
zero = zeroEle.text
print zero

browser.quit()
```

Suggestions:

1. `tbl = driver.find_element_by_name("Site no.")`: use the method when `name="Site no."` specified in HTML. In the given HTML, `Site no.` is not a value of a ``name` attribute. so, you can't use it.
2. `tbl = driver.find_element_by_text('Site no.')`: There is no such method defined in WebDriver. the original method is `find_element_by_link_text`. this method is used to find the elements with `a` tag links but not for all elements in the HTML. There is no way you can get an element using the text of that element (Except links i.e., `a` tags text).